# Simplify 4-element multinomial distribution where there are only 2 unique probabilities

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-theorem

I am having some trouble understanding if the following expression can be simplified

\begin{equation}
    \binom{m}{b, c'-b, c-b, m+b-(c'+c)} P_s^{m+2b-(c'+c)} (1-P_s)^{((c'+c)-2b)}
\end{equation}

where $0<P_s<1$.

Notice here that the probabilities of picking the first and last element in the multinomial coefficient are the same ($P_s$), and the probabilities of the second and third are the same ($1-P_s$). Given this symmetry, is there any way to simplify the coefficient?

Thanks,
James

Comment: From where has $x$ come ?

Comment: And what is the difficulty You only have to add/subtract coefficients to reduce the probability to a form $(P_s)^k$, assuming $x$ is a typo for $'$

Comment: Yes thank you $x$ was a typo for $^\prime$. And I am not sure what you mean by this comment about adding and subtracting ..

Answer (score 1):

The first check you need to make is that all the coefficients add up to $m$, as they must; which they do.

Collect the coefficients of the $2{nd}$ and $3{rd}$  terms: $(c+c'-2b)$

Cleaning up the clutter of symbols, I replace $(c+c'-2b)\;to\; a$ and $P_s\; to\; p$,

Then the **probabilities part** of the expression will simply be

$\Large p^{m-a}\cdot(1-p)^a$

*ADDED*

If it is the *multinomial coefficient* you were talking about, there's nothing, really,you can do, except, maybe, put parts with the same probability in adjoining manner, viz

$$\binom{m}{b,\;\, m+b-(c'+c),\;\,c'-b,\;\,c-b}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was hoping for some further simplification and assuming I was missing some intuition regarding what multinomial distributions look like with equal probabilities, but it sounds like this is not the case. Regardless I very much appreciate the answer!

Comment: Thank you, I regret that no further simplification is possible.